# Fundamental groups of Calabi-Yau varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, calabi-yau

By a Calabi-Yau variety I mean a smooth projective variety over the complex numbers with numerically trivial canonical divisor.

> For each postive integer $n$ does there exist a finite group $G$ (possibly depending on $n$) which is not the fundamental group of a Calabi-Yau variety of dimension $n$?

For $n=1,2$ this follows easily from the classification of Calabi-Yau varieties of these dimensions, the only non-trivial finite fundamental group being $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (for Enriques surfaces). For $n=3$ some finite non-abelian groups are known to occur as fundamental groups but I do not know of any non-existence results.

If there are only finitely many families of Calabi-Yau varieties of a given dimension then the question would clearly have a positive answer. However, this is far from being known so I am interested in other possible approaches.

Answer (score 10):

If n is even, then I believe you can use the Atiyah-Bott fixed point formula to rule out many cases.  For instance, let G be a simple, non-cyclic group.  Consider the action of G on the Hodge group $H^{0,n}(X)$.  Since G has only the trivial character, this action must be trivial.  Then for every element g in G, the holomorphic Lefschetz number is 2 (if n is odd, the number is 0, which doesn't help).  Therefore g has a fixed point.

Comment: Of course I should hasten to add, I (as most complex geometers) define "Calabi-Yau" to mean that $h^{0,p}(X)$ equals $0$ except for $p=0$ and $p=n$ (use Berger's theorem to break up into Calabi-Yau, hyper-Kaehler and Abelian variety factors).

Answer (score 8):

This is definitely not an easy question. For $n=3$ checkout the paper [Calabi-Yau Threefolds of Quotient Type](http://www.intlpress.com/AJM/p/2001/5_1/AJM-5-1-043-078.pdf) by Oguiso and Sakurai. They are ("only") concerned with whether the fundamental group is finite. However, that should perhaps be the first step towards answering your question.