# A Calabi-Yau manifold with finite simple fundamental group?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, calabi-yau

Is there a known example of a Calabi-Yau manifold (say, a Kähler compact manifold with $c_1$ torsion) with finite simple (non cyclic) fundamental group, for instance $\mathfrak{A}_5$? I am pretty sure such an example is not known in dimension 3 (see [this paper](http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/ahep/2011/901898.pdf)<sup>1</sup>), but perhaps it is easier to find it in higher dimension (?).

<sup>1</sup>*Davies, Rhys*, [**The expanding zoo of Calabi-Yau threefolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1155/2011/901898), Adv. High Energy Phys. 2011, Article ID 901898, 18 p. (2011). [ZBL1234.81110](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1234.81110), [MR2821564](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2821564).

Comment: Please see my answer to the following MO question (which rules out all Calabi-Yau manifolds of even dimension): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65208/fundamental-groups-of-calabi-yau-varieties/65210#65210

Comment: @Jason Starr: Well, I didn't rule out holomorphic symplectic manifolds. But I agree that finding a IHS manifold with a free action of $\mathfrak{A}_5$, hence of dimension $2(60k-1)$, is extremely unlikely. I had in mind the odd-dimensional case.